# Как правильно сформировать Procfile Django-проекта для Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Пользуюсь данной документацией [Configuring Django Apps for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration).

Пробую указать путь до wsgi, но всё равно получаю ошибку. Как правильно составить procfile в моем случае?

**Логи heroku**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn app.blogengine.blogengine.wsgi
```

**Структура проекта**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**requirements.txt**

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.3
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

В **settings.py** добавил

```
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals()
```

Comment: Судя по наличии папки venv, вы используйте виртуальное окружение в python. Если так, то это следует указать при запуске gunicorn. Как, смотрите в документации

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно на Heroku загрузить только папку проекта (blogengine). Внутри этой папки необходимо расположить requirements.txt; и Procfile со следующим содержимым (для вашего случая):

```
web: gunicorn blogengine.wsgi --log-file -
```

В данном случае, при правильных командах все будет работать.

Comment: Убрал папку app, перенёс Procfile и requirements.txt в blogengine, Procfile исправил.
Теперь возникла проблема с buildpack. Удалил его и установил снова, но всё равно не помогло.

Нашел вопрос двух годичной давности по моей проблеме [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku).

Автор решил проблему просто создав новое приложение. Мне такое не помогло.